# Thread not waking up after notifyAll();

Tags: java, multithreading

OK, So I have these classes that extend Thread, what I'm supposed to do is:

1. Let all alumns arrive.
2. When alumns arrive they say 'Hi'.
3. If the teacher arrives but not all of the Alumns have arrived then he should wait() for them.
4. Alumns should notify() the teacher when they're all there.

An alumn is a Thread initialized with boolean value 0.

A teacher is a Thread initialized with boolean value 1.

**Person/Greeting Code**

```
    public class Person extends Thread {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;
    boolean id;
    Greeting greeting;
    public Person(String name,boolean tipo,int n){
        this.threadName = name;
        this.id=tipo;  
        greeting =new Greeting();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(id==false) { 
            try {
                greeting.alumn(threadName);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            try {
                greeting.teacher(threadName);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
    public void start() 
  {
    System.out.println("Starting "+ threadName);
    if(t==null)
    {
      t=new Thread(this,threadName);
      t.start();
    }
  }
}

class Greeting {

    public void alumn(String s) throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println(s);
       synchronized (this){
            System.out.println("Alumn: "+s);
            notifyAll();       
    }
    }

    public synchronized void teacher(String s) throws InterruptedException {
        wait();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class ClassRoom {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Person francisco = new Person("Francisco",false,1);
        Person jesus = new Person("Jesus", false,2);
        Person alberto = new Person("Alberto",false,3);
        Person karla = new Person("Karla",false,4);
        Person maestro = new Person("Professor",true,0);
        francisco.start();
        jesus.start();
        alberto.start();
        karla.start();
        maestro.start();
    }
}
```

**The problem:**
If the teacher arrives first he goes to wait()...then alumns arrive but he never wakes up.
If the teacher doesn't arrive first, he still never wakes up!
How to fix this?

Comment: @DavidWallace I didn't know that, but anyway, shouldn't the last alumn who arrived wake up the teacher who's been waiting?

Comment: Sorry about the last comment.  I didn't see that only one `Thread` was sleeping.  Each of these `Person` objects both "is a" `Thread` and "has a" `Thread`.  I think you should decide whether you're using inheritance or composition and stick to it, rather than mixing them.  In other words, either have `Person extends Thread` or have a `Thread` field, but not both.  Either will work, but you're doing things like overriding `start()`, which doesn't make sense either way.

Comment: Does your assignment require you to use `wait()` and `notify()`? Or are you allowed to use something like `join()`? Or even a `CountDownLatch`?

Comment: Well, right now the topic is wait and notify/All(). So yeah, It'd be nice to use them! But worry not, post your answers!

Answer (score 2):

> If the teacher arrives first he goes to wait()...then alumns arrive
>   but he never wakes up.

All you Persons instantiate their own Greeting, which synchronzizes on `this` and therefore also waits/notifies on `this`. Each Person uses its own semaphore, which is not what you want. You should synchronize on the same object (perhaps `Greeting.class`) for all instances.

> If the teacher doesn't arrive first, he still never wakes up! How to fix this?

Simply check if all alumns are there. If yes greet, else wait for notify. Afterwards check again. The check has to be part of the synchronized block to avoid race conditions.

Comment: exactly, I was just typing this. One addition: maybe you should understand the greeting as a message to the Room. actually the Persons do not greet a single other Person but more tell it to all in the room. Then the room keeps track of the amount of persons in and when the Teacher arrives,he just asks for the current amount and then waits for all changes until the expected amount of persons is reached.

Comment: Correct, this would be a cleaner model for this situation. It offers a nice solution for the "Is everybody there"-part.

Answer (score 0):

To wait until all threads has arrived to certain point, consider using `CyclicBarrier`.